# How to perform addition of same keys' values of objects and return unique objects from array of objects using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

am working on a task where I get a response consists of array of objects.

Now, I want to perform addition on some fields based on particular conditions and return new and unique array of objects without any duplicates.

Here is the response.

```
let respData = [
  {
     "NEW": 0,
     "Working": 0,
     "Not Working": 2,
     "Broken": 0,
     "Location": "Karimnagar",
     "TotalPrice": 274500,
     "AssetsCount": 2,
     "AssetType": "Hardware Devices"
  },{
     "NEW": 1,
     "Working": 0,
     "Not Working": 0,
     "Broken": 0,
     "Location": "chennai",
     "TotalPrice": 4500,
     "AssetsCount": 1,
     "AssetType": "Undefined"
  },{
     "NEW": 0,
     "Working": 0,
     "Not Working": 0,
     "Broken": 0,
     "Location": "Undefined",
     "TotalPrice": 0,
     "AssetsCount": 1,
     "AssetType": "Undefined"
  },{
     "NEW": 1,
     "Working": 0,
     "Not Working": 0,
     "Broken": 0,
     "Location": "Karimnagar",
     "TotalPrice": 12500,
     "AssetsCount": 1,
     "AssetType": "Hardware Devices"
  },{
     "NEW": 0,
     "Working": 1,
     "Not Working": 0,
     "Broken": 0,
     "Location": "Karimnagar",
     "TotalPrice": 1200,
     "AssetsCount": 1,
     "AssetType": "Hardware Devices"
  }
]
```

Now am trying to add the integer values in objects if `AssetType` and `Location` are same.

If there are not matching results present, need to return them as it is.

And after adding them, I need to return unique array of objects with all updated values.

I've tried with `map` and `filter` to get the result, but couldn't get the correct result.

This is the code I've tried.

```
let respCopy = respData;
let finalObj = {}, testArray = [];

respCopy.forEach((copyData, i) => {
        respData.forEach((data, j) => {
            if(i !== j && copyData.AssetType === data.AssetType && copyData.Location === data.Location){
                assetConditions.forEach((condition, k) => {
                    if(copyData[condition.name]){
                        finalObj[condition.name] = copyData[condition.name] + data[condition.name];
                        finalObj["AssetType"] = copyData.AssetType;
                        finalObj["Location"] = copyData.Location;
                        copyData[condition.name] = 0;
                        data[condition.name] = 0;
                    }
                })
            }else if(i == j && copyData.AssetType === data.AssetType && copyData.Location === data.Location){
                assetConditions.forEach((condition, k) => {
                    if(copyData[condition.name]){
                        finalObj[condition.name] = copyData[condition.name];
                        finalObj["AssetType"] = copyData.AssetType;
                        finalObj["Location"] = copyData.Location;
                        copyData[condition.name] = 0;
                        data[condition.name] = 0;
                    }
                })
            }
        });
        testArray.push(finalObj);
    })
```

This is the expected result.

```
[
  {
     "NEW": 1,
     "Working": 1,
     "Not Working": 2,
     "Broken": 0,
     "Location": "Karimnagar",
     "TotalPrice": 288200,
     "AssetsCount": 4,
     "AssetType": "Hardware Devices"
  },{
     "NEW": 1,
     "Working": 0,
     "Not Working": 0,
     "Broken": 0,
     "Location": "chennai",
     "TotalPrice": 4500,
     "AssetsCount": 1,
     "AssetType": "Undefined"
  },{
     "NEW": 0,
     "Working": 0,
     "Not Working": 0,
     "Broken": 0,
     "Location": "Undefined",
     "TotalPrice": 0,
     "AssetsCount": 1,
     "AssetType": "Undefined"
  }
]
```

[Code I've tried in Codepen](https://codepen.io/aravind_5516/pen/jOMXzba?editors=0012)

Is there anything am making mistakes in getting the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of issues can be easily solved using a dictionary object as a proxy.

You have to define the object's keys as your unique identifier (in your case a concatenation of `AssetType` and `Location` values) then map them to the objects you want to create a unique array of.

Eventually you'll want to return the `Object.values()` of your dictionary object:

```js
const arrayWithDuplicates = [{
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
    foo: 1
  },
  {
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
    foo: 2
  }, // Note the two first elements have identical keys
  {
    key1: 3,
    key2: 2,
    foo: 3
  },
];

function getDictKey(element) {
  // This can obviously be implemented otherwise
  const { key1, key2 } = element;
  return `${key1}_${key2}`;
}

const dictionary = {};
arrayWithDuplicates.forEach((element) => {
  const key = getDictKey(element);

  if (dictionary[key]) {
    dictionary[key].foo += element.foo;
  } else {
    dictionary[key] = element;
  }
});

const arrayWithoutDuplicates = Object.values(dictionary);
console.log(arrayWithoutDuplicates);
```